# Mobilefirst : Specify which file i want to build to device

Tags: build, ibm-mobilefirst

I have gulp + node_modules + test folders in my common, how can i tell mobilefirst not to build those folders into devices when i build for android , wp , ios or blackberry ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in MobileFirst to do this. You can however use Apache Ant tasks to be run *after* the MFPF build, to remove those folders from the generated native folder.

You can see an example of Ant integration in the following blog post.
You just need to replace the Ant task with the one that suits your needs: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/